# C# weird string behaviour?

Tags: c#, string, equals

I have a string variable as below:

```
string testVar = "abc ";
```

Then I have a `if` statement as below:

```
if(this.testVar[this.testVar.Length-1].Equals(" "))
```

From the above I'm trying to find if the last character is space, if it is space then do something. But it is always false even if my `testVar = "abc "`?

Comment: your are comparing `char` and `string`

Comment: You wouldn't compare a char and a string there?

Comment: If you instead want to include all white-space characters like  spaces,tab or new-lines use: `if(Char.IsWhiteSpace(this.testVar.Last()))...` (which is also more readable imho)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`testVar[…]` returns a *`char`*, not a `string`. That’s why an `Equals` test with a `string` always returns `false`. You can fix this easily by comparing to a `char`. you also don’t need `Equals`:

```
if (testVar[testVar.Length - 1] == ' ')
```

It is worth nothing that, if you had used `==` initially instead of `Equals`, you would have gotten a *compile time error* explaining the problem. This illustrates nicely why it’s good to use early binding rather than late binding (`Equals` takes an `object` and hence doesn’t offer compile-time type checking).

Answer (score 4):

Why do you not just use:

```
if (testVar.EndsWith (" "))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always false because a `char` is never equal to a `string`.

This would work:

```
if (this.testVar[this.testVar.Length-1].Equals(' '))
```

or this

```
if (this.testVar[this.testVar.Length-1] == ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

check this dude

```
var result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question, let alone answer it?